# Reshape multiple response survey data in R

Tags: r, reshape, survey

I am working with survey data in R that has a multiple response question.

Currently my data looks like:

```
Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3 Q1_4
1       1    0    0
1       0    0    0 
0       1    1    0 
1       0    0    0
```

I would like it to look like this so I can create a bar chart comparing the counts:

```
Q1     Count 
Q1_1     3
Q1_2     2
Q1_3     1 
Q1_4     0
```

I am a newcomer to R and have no idea where to start. How would I restructure this?

Comment: Take a look at the `colSums` function.  It can provide the desired summary for your data.

Answer (score 2):

This is one option that will give you a dataset as an output so you can use it to plot:

```
df = read.table(text = "
Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3 Q1_4
1       1    0    0
1       0    0    0 
0       1    1    0 
1       0    0    0
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(col, value) %>%         # reshape data
  group_by(col) %>%              # for every column name
  summarise(Count = sum(value))  # get sum of values

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    col  Count
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 Q1_1      3
# 2 Q1_2      2
# 3 Q1_3      1
# 4 Q1_4      0
```

Another options is this

```
df %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%  # get the sum for each column
  gather(col, value)      # reshape data

#    col value
# 1 Q1_1     3
# 2 Q1_2     2
# 3 Q1_3     1
# 4 Q1_4     0
```

You can also use `colSums`, but you'll need to get and save the column names as a column in your new dataset:

```
res = colSums(df)

data.frame(col = names(res),
           Count = res)

#       col Count
# Q1_1 Q1_1     3
# Q1_2 Q1_2     2
# Q1_3 Q1_3     1
# Q1_4 Q1_4     0
```